# how would I write a script in bash to check if grep finds needed string

Tags: bash

I want to write a script in bash that checks if grep finds needed string inside tarfile.

```
tar xvf test.tar -O | grep "exynos7870"
```

but this just checks it. What I want to do is:

if `Binary file (standard input) matches`  do something

Comment: `tar xvf test.tar -O | grep "exynos7870" && do_something`

Comment: `if tar xvf test.tar -O | grep "exynos7870"; then do_something; else do_another_thing; fi`

Comment: It's generally quicker, if you just want to know if a file contains something, to use `grep -m1` so it can stop searching at the first match. You probably want `grep -q` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the -a flag to directly read through the binary file.

```
if grep -qa -m1 "exynos7870" test.tar 
then 
    echo yes;
else
    echo no;
fi
```